# can I rotate the button or label into vertically in java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want button in vertically, for that i can extend the height and shrink the width of that button. But the text of the lable of buttons are in the form of horizontal only. For that can i rotate the whole button vertically and is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) shows how the text and icon can be rotated on the button (or any component that uses icons.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to pre-rotate the labels and just have it as an image on the button.

You might also want to take a look at this solution given in sun's forum for [rotating a JButton](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10103625#10103625).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with scene graph: https://scenegraph.dev.java.net/